# Redirect a logged in user from login page to user dashboard with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, redirect

I need your help to manage a php page with redirection function.

I want my logged in users to redirect to user dashboard instead of displaying login page by typing address in Browser's address Bar. How to prevent users to display login page

Login page codes are given below

```
<?php 

include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['user_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
    $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
      $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";

}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
            AND `banned` = '0'
            ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 

    list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$approved) {
    //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
    $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";

    //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
     //exit();
     }

        //check against salt
    if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
    if(empty($err)){            

     // this sets session and logs user in  
       session_start();
       session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

       // this sets variables in the session 
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
        $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        //update the timestamp and key for cookie
        $stamp = time();
        $ckey = GenKey();
        mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        //set a cookie 

       if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                  setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                   }
          header("Location: dashboard.php");
         }
        }
        else
        {
        //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
        $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
        //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
        }
    } else {
        $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
      }     
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a session with the user data, so, it's simple, save the status in the same session and make a verification on the top of your script. Like this

Put this in your code

```
    // this sets variables in the session 
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $_SESSION['status_logged'] = true; //new line
```

And put a verification on the top:

```
    if (isset ($_SESSION['status_logged']) && $_SESSION['status_logged'] == true) {
        header('Location: yourDashboardPage.php');
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['status_logged'] = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. How i can put this verification on top? You mean just after opening of php code

Comment: Sorry, Dear, it didn't work. When i put these codes on my page i got the same thing, It didn't redirect to dashboard.

Comment: Post your error log. 
The name of your dashboardpage is "dashboard.php"? This is only a example, you must use the real name of your page. If this doesn't  work, try to use the complete path of your page like '/var/www/path_to_your_app/yourDashboardPage.php', for example.

Answer (score 0):

I put your codes like this but got no effect. So please elaborate well and give example how to do it exactly.

```
<?php 

include 'dbc.php';

if (isset ($_SESSION['status_logged']) && $_SESSION['status_logged'] = true) {
        header('Location: dashboards.php');
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['status_logged'] = false;
    }

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['user_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
    $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
      $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";

}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
            AND `banned` = '0'
            ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 

    list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$approved) {
    //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
    $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";

    //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
     //exit();
     }

        //check against salt
    if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
    if(empty($err)){            

     // this sets session and logs user in  
       session_start();
       session_regenerate_id (true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

        // this sets variables in the session 
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $_SESSION['status_logged'] = true; //new line

        //update the timestamp and key for cookie
        $stamp = time();
        $ckey = GenKey();
        mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        //set a cookie 

       if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                  setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                   }
          header("Location: dashboard.php");
         }
        }
        else
        {
        //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
        $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
        //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
        }
    } else {
        $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
      }     
}



?>
```